# I have a problem in android studio using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-realtime-database

All though I have added google-services.json in my android project but when started to build it shows error that google plugin can't function without it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Tool -> Firebase
Then add all dependency
Also add your SHA-256 key in firebase under your project.